# React JS: Displaying Blank Page When Passing Parameters to Child Component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am building a React application where I have a parent component (PetDetailsPage) that retrieves pet details from the backend API using axios. The pet details are fetched based on a petID parameter from the URL using useParams from react-router-dom. The retrieved data is then passed as a prop (petDetails) to a child component (PetDetails) responsible for rendering the pet information.

The issue I am facing is that when I navigate to the PetDetailsPage with a valid petID parameter, the data is successfully fetched from the backend, but the child component (PetDetails) displays a blank page. It seems that the petDetails prop is not being received or rendered properly.

I have confirmed that the data is being fetched correctly, and there are no errors in the console. However, the content of PetDetails is not showing up when the data is available.

I have tried adding conditional rendering in the PetDetails component to handle the case when petDetails is null or undefined, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Can someone please help me identify why the PetDetails component is not displaying the pet information when the data is available? What am I missing in my implementation, and how can I properly render the PetDetails component with the fetched pet details?

Any insights, suggestions, or code examples to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

PetDetailsPage.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PetDetailsBread from '../components/petdetailscomponent/PetDetailsBread';
import PetDetails from '../components/petdetailscomponent/PetDetails';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

function PetDetailsPage() {
  const { petID } = useParams();
  const [petDetails, setPetDetails] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to fetch pet details from the backend API
    const getPetById = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/pets/${petID}`);
        setPetDetails(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching pet details:', error);
      }
    };

    getPetById();
  }, [petID]);

  return (
    <main>
      <PetDetailsBread petID={petID} />
      <PetDetails petDetails={petDetails} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default PetDetailsPage;
```

PetDetails.js

```
import React  from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
function PetDetails({ petDetails }) {

  return (
    <section className="pet-details-area">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-8">
            <div className="pet-details-content">
              <h4 className="title">{petDetails.tbl_petdetail.petName}</h4>
             
              <div className="pet-details-img">
              <img src={petDetails.tbl_petdetail.petImg} alt={petDetails.tbl_petdetail.petName} />
              </div>
              <h4 className="title">About Bio</h4>
              <p>{petDetails.tbl_petdetail.petDesc}</p>
              <div className="keynote-dog-info">
                <h5 className="title">Dog Information</h5>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div className="keynote-info-item">
                      <h6>Gender:</h6>
                      <span>Male</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div className="keynote-info-item">
                      <h6>Age:</h6>
                      <span>1 year</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div className="keynote-info-item">
                      <h6>Color:</h6>
                      <span>White</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div className="keynote-info-item">
                      <h6>Pet ID:</h6>
                      <span>09481</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div className="keynote-info-item">
                      <h6>Size:</h6>
                      <span>Med. 26-60 lbs</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div className="keynote-info-item">
                      <h6>Gender:</h6>
                      <span>Male</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div className="keynote-info-item">
                      <h6>City:</h6>
                      <span>New York</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
                    <div className="keynote-info-item">
                      <h6>Breed:</h6>
                      <span>Husky</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <Link to="/contacts" className="btn">Apply Today <img src="img/icon/w_pawprint.png" alt="" /></Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-4">
            <aside className="keynote-sidebar">
              <div className="widget keynote-widget">
                <div className="keynote-widget-title mb-20">
                  <h5 className="title">Find Your Pets</h5>
                </div>
                <form className="sidebar-find-pets">
                  <div className="form-grp search-box">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                    <button><i className="fas fa-search" /></button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-grp">
                    <i className="flaticon-location" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Location" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-6">
                      <div className="form-grp">
                        <i className="flaticon-color-palette" />
                        <input type="text" placeholder="White" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-6">
                      <div className="form-grp">
                        <i className="far fa-calendar-alt" />
                        <input type="text" defaultValue={2021} />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-grp">
                    <i className="flaticon-sex" />
                    <select name="name" className="selected">
                      <option value>Female</option>
                      <option value>Male</option>
                      <option value>Adoption</option>
                      <option value>keynote</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-grp">
                    <i className="fas fa-dollar-sign" />
                    <select name="name" className="selected">
                      <option value>Price</option>
                      <option value>$100 - $150</option>
                      <option value>$150 - $250</option>
                      <option value>$250 - $350</option>
                      <option value>$350 - $550</option>
                      <option value>$550 - $1000</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-grp">
                    <i className="flaticon-plus-18-movie" />
                    <select name="name" className="selected">
                      <option value>Adult :</option>
                      <option value>6 Month</option>
                      <option value>9 Month</option>
                      <option value>1 Year</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <button className="btn">Find New Pets</button>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div className="widget sidebar-newsletter">
                <div className="sn-icon">
                  <img src="img/icon/sn_icon.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div className="sn-title">
                  <h4 className="title">Subscribe Newsletter</h4>
                  <p>Sign-up For Latest News</p>
                </div>
                <form className="sn-form">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
                  <button className="btn">subscribe</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </aside>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default PetDetails;
```

Comment: In order to debug properly you could do a console.log('petDetails', petDetails) right before the useEffect in order to see if the retrieved data is the one expected, maybe it is wrapped in a { data: [object] } or something similar, your code looks good to me

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a loading

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PetDetailsBread from '../components/petdetailscomponent/PetDetailsBread';
import PetDetails from '../components/petdetailscomponent/PetDetails';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

function PetDetailsPage() {
  const { petID } = useParams();
  const [petDetails, setPetDetails] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to fetch pet details from the backend API
    const getPetId = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/pets/${petID}`);
        setPetDetails(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching pet details:', error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    getPetId();
  }, [petID]);

  return (
    <main>
      <PetDetailsBread petID={petID} />
      {loading ? (
        <div id="preloader">
          <img src="/img/preloader.gif" alt="" />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <PetDetails petDetails={petDetails} />
      )}
    </main>
  );
}

export default PetDetailsPage;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).